# Error in browser console "DEPRECATED: The widget module is deprecated. Please consider using the sdk/ui module instead."

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using addon-sdk for developing an extension.When I ran my code using `cfx run` on Firefox 32.0 and checked the browser console it shows following:

```
"DEPRECATED: The widget module is deprecated.  Please consider using the sdk/ui module instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 114, in startup/<
run(options);
File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 170, in run
let program = main(options.loader, options.main);
File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 645, in main
return loader.load(loader, module).exports;
File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
result = load(loader, module);
File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 299, in load
evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 262, in evaluate
: loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
File "resource://skype_ff_extension-at-jetpack/skype_ff_extension/lib/main.js", line 14, in null
var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 619, in require
freeze(load(loader, module));
File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
result = load(loader, module);
File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 299, in load
evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 262, in evaluate
: loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js", line 60, in null
"The widget module is deprecated.  " +
File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/util/deprecate.js", line 18, in deprecateUsage
let stack = get().slice(2);"
```

How to debug this error?

PS:To anyone who see this error first check if its your add-on or any other add-on which is throwing this error.

Comment: Solution is to discontinue using that `require('widget')` and move to `require('sdk/ui')`: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/03/13/new-add-on-sdk-australis-ui-features-in-firefox-29/

Comment: See the "Deprecated" note on the doc page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/widget

Comment: Thanks! but in my case it was Skype extension that was throwing this error :(

Comment: @Blagoh Would be better make this a proper answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to edit code in the add-on. Take out that `require('widget')` and move to `require('sdk/ui')`: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/03/13/new-add-on-sdk-australis-ui-features-in-firefox-29/

Once you change to `sdk/ui`, you have to change how the add-on was making widgets to use the sdk/ui. Lean about that by:

> See and follow the links in the note "Deprecated" seen on the documentation page of `widget` module: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/widget

Comment: have not used require('widget') in the entire code, still getting this error

Answer (score 2):

open about:support

then search there Skype Click to Call plugin ID

and remove file with name

`{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi`

from your

```
mozilla_installation_path\browser\extensions\
(c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `extensions.sdk.console.logLevel; all` from `about:config` and replacing it with `extensions.YOUR_EXTENSION_ID.sdk.console.logLevel; all`

This should return the log level to the default of `error`, meaning you won't see any other extensions' `console.log` output.

---

### Edit

The above still shows other extensions' error messages, if you want to remove them, do the following.

Check out [this post](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2013/03/27/changes-to-console-log-behaviour-in-sdk-1-14/) for an explanation. Essentially, you add a string to `about:config` (by right-clicking) called `extensions.sdk.console.logLevel` and set it to `off`, then add the string `extensions.YOUR_EXTENSION_ID.sdk.console.logLevel` and set it to `all`.

Comment: Rather than hide the message thrown by the error I think he's wondering how to fix the error. This error he's seeing is making the add-on unusable likely, he might as well uninstall the add-on rather than go with your solution.

Comment: I uninstalled the add-on which was throwing the error

Comment: @Blagoh Yeah exactly I was trying to find and fix the error in my add-on

Comment: @willlma I can't find `extensions.sdk.console.logLevel; all` in `about:config`

Comment: @AshishGupta See my updated answer. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Blagoh this answer is still useful if the error isn't making the add-on unusable and the add-on isn't his.

Comment: Anything and everything can be considered helpful if the context is right.